# is it possible to check how many DIMM slots are filled in a pc motherboard, remotely?

Tags: windows, memory, remote-access

I am basically away from my office, but would like to check whether a pc (which has 4GB of RAM) has 4x 1GB DIMMs or 2x 2GB DIMMs.

I am referring to a windows XP system. Is it possible to gather this info from System information or otherwise, remotely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have remote desktop, just install and run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

Answer (score 15):

Windows itself doesn't show this anywher as far as I know.
You will have to run a utility like CPU-Z on the system itself to determine this.

If you have an Intel AMT infrastructure you can probably query this through that, but those are pretty rare in the wild. (I have never seen one.)

It is possible to query this via WMIC, but I don't know this is available on XP. A quick attempt shows it appears to work on Win7.

> wmic memorychip get Capacity /format:list

Will give  a line for each chip with the capcity in bytes.

Comment: For those looking for a PowerShell answer, you can use [`Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx) to access the same data as `wmic memorychip`.